# Could a Trill Symbiont join a non-Trill humanoid?

Tags: star-trek

I know that Dax joined Odo, but could the Symbiosis Institute approve that?

Comment: Don't recall the episode (hence this a comment), but in TNG, Riker hosts a symbiont for a short time to keep it alive until a new host can make it to the Enterprise, but I believe he is told that if he keeps the symbiont too long, it will kill them both.

Comment: @Roger - The symbiote/host relationship in TNG: The Host was radically different. Basically the host body was just that, a grown host that had no personality and was essentially a meat-puppet for the intelligent symbiote.

Comment: slightly off topic but the guys on the Mission Log Podcast raise a very interesting point as to the meat puppet aspect of that episode and Beverly's.....interaction with the Riker puppet, i.e. - that might not have been what exactly what Riker signed up for...

Comment: @Valorum - indeed, the differences are so great that they could be considered an entirely different species.

Comment: I don't think Dax ever joined Odo.  You're probably thinking of *Facets*, where Curzon Dax's personality and memories were transferred to Odo telepathically - not the same thing as a joining.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, kind of. In the Next Generation episode [The Host](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Host_(episode)), the Trill ambassador Odan is on the Enterprise. When the host is killed, the symbiont is temporarily implanted in Riker to keep it alive, which seems to be successful. After a few days, Riker's body starts to have an immune reaction to the symbiont in him, so this probably can't be done on a long-term basis.

***However***, Deep Space Nine retcons a lot about Trill physiology.

- In TNG, the Trill don't use the transporter, as it would kill the symbiont (for some reason). In DS9, Trills transport just fine.
- In TNG, the Trill hosts have rubber foreheads and pale makeup. In DS9, Trills have spots.
- In TNG, the Trill symbionts look a bit like brains with tails. In DS9, they look like non-descript brown slugs.
- And, finally, the big one. In TNG, the symbiont entirely takes over the personality and thought processes of the host. In DS9, it's a blending of host and symbiont.

I have heard that one or two of the novels rationalize this by positing that there are subspecies of Trill and Trill symbionts, but this has never been shown on screen.

Out of universe, the reason for the make-up change was either because Terry Farrell was allergic to the prosthetics, didn't look good in them, or both (I've heard both stories). Farrell's allergy to prosthetics is also why Dax never appeared as a Klingon in the DS9 episode [Apocalypse Rising](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Rising_(episode)), even though Dax's knowledge and love of Klingon culture would have made her a perfect fit for the mission. (This bit of trivia is also referenced in the linked Memory Alpha page.)

Finally, Dax never joined Odo. That was the result of the Trill zhian'tara ritual shown in the episode [Facets](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Facets_(episode)). The ritual allows others to temporarily host the memories and personality of previous joinings, but it's not the same thing as a joining. Since Odo is a shapeshifter, the transference had the effect of making him look more like Curzon.

Politically speaking, the [Symbiosis Commission](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Symbiosis_Commission) had strict requirements for potential Trill hosts due to limited supply of symbionts. It also suppressed information about how many Trill were actually suitable for joining so that people would not view them as commodities or fight over them. Although it never came up in the show, it would be perfectly in-character for the Symbiosis Commission to refuse to even consider non-Trill candidates even if they were physically capable of carrying the symbionts, which, as established above, is not a sure thing. Allowing non-Trill hosts would most likely have similar societal effects to the knowledge of the true number of Trill who could be joined.

Edited to add (and spoilered since this is brand new):

> In the Discovery episode [People of Earth](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/People_of_Earth_(episode)), the character Adira is introduced who is a human joined with the Trill symbiont Tal. Time will tell how well this joining holds up, although, with the medical technology of the time period, it might be made to work. Also of note is that Adira has trouble accessing Tal's memories. Whether that's due to inexperience or species is unclear as of yet. Since communication and travel is more limited in this setting, it seems unlikely that the Symbiosis Commission (if it even still exists) was asked for permission.

Comment: If memory serves It wasn't an allergy to the latex that prevented her having the facial ridges, it was the fact they'd cast an attractive woman and weren't keen to cover her face up.

Comment: @Valorum Not going to deny that was a likely consideration too, though I'd forgotten that part of the story. I've edited it into my answer.

Comment: @Valorum That was the reason for the Bajoran makeup when Michelle Forbes was first shown as Ro Laren - something along the lines of "We have a pretty girl, let's keep her that way".

Comment: Terry Farrell makeup test images with more tng style trill are  easily found now.  But since it was much lighter than tng it looked merely like a raised line in the middle of her forehead.

Comment: Adira has problems accessing her symbiont's memories, though. This may be a thing of age and training, but relevant IMHO.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Good point. Added.

Answer (score 5):

*Star Trek: Discovery* S03E04 sheds some light on this:

> Comissioner Voss, part of the leading group of Trill, tells us: "There hasn't been a record of a successful joining between a symbiont and a non-trill host in over 2,000 years."

Commissioner Voss also calls the very idea of non-trill hosts "abhorrent" and the trill leader rejects this as well.

Thus, a joining with anything but trill hosts would most definitely not be *approved* within the relevant timeframe of Star Trek (the time between the very first episode of *ENT* and current *DIS* episodes). Especially in a situation where there still is a stable culture and population.

There is only a very slight chance it may be accepted after the fact as the decision of the symbiont, though.

> As it happened in the case of Adira, **opening the prospect** of a change of policies at the end of the episode. It is actually a *plot point* that the trill have to move away from their narrow-mindedness if they want their culture to prevail.

Comment: @Valorum: It is one of the guardians who literally said this quote to Adira when "welcoming" her on the planet. How would they risk to lose a symbiont?

Comment: @Valorum Done. Also, even if there may have been successful joinings with other species prior to that, it is pretty obvious that the relevant time frame of Star Trek pretty much makes it a no-no categorically. See edits.

Comment: Much better. Have an upvote

Answer (score 3):

The Symbiosis Commission would likely not approve such a joining, because demand for symbionts among the native Trill population far exceeds the supply.

> In the 24th century, about 500 symbionts became available for joining, each year, compared to approximately 5,000 Trill becoming initiates per annum. The relatively low quantity of symbionts resulted in Trill society hiding from their general populace the fact that virtually 50% of the population was suitable for joining, and the general belief in the 24th century was consequently that only one in every 1,000 Trills was suitable for joining. (DS9: "Equilibrium")
>
> *Memory Alpha: [Trill symbiont](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trill_symbiont)*

Comment: I think this could be expanded.  I'm sure there's biological reasons for it.  The part you've quoted is really an internal political thing for the Trill.

Comment: I got the impression the OP was specifically interested in the political issue, but maybe I misunderstood.  I'd guess, though, that the Symbiosis Commission just wouldn't *do* research on the biological aspects; politics would make that taboo.